# Cisco 3750 switch not communicating with RADIUS server

Tags: cisco, switch, radius, aaa

I have a Cisco 3750 switch and I want to make it work with PacketFence NAC. I have configured the switch according to their network configuration document [here](https://packetfence.org/doc/PacketFence_Network_Devices_Configuration_Guide.html), but the switch is still not communicating with the server - I can ping the server and keys are the same.
Here is my running-config (stripped of non-related things)

```
Current configuration : 8496 bytes
!
aaa new-model
!
!
aaa group server radius packetfence
 server name pfnac
!
aaa authentication login default local
aaa authentication dot1x default group packetfence
aaa authorization exec default local 
aaa authorization network default group packetfence 
!
!
aaa server radius dynamic-author
 client 147.32.232.117 server-key 7 0311480E351B3343400E1C172417081E013E
 port 3799
!
aaa session-id common
!
!
!
dot1x system-auth-control
!
!         
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
 description 10.D16
 switchport access vlan 40
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security maximum 1 vlan access
 switchport port-security
 switchport port-security violation restrict
 switchport port-security mac-address 0200.0001.0101
 authentication order dot1x mab
 authentication priority dot1x mab
 authentication port-control auto
 authentication periodic
 authentication timer restart 10800
 authentication timer reauthenticate 7200
 authentication violation replace
 mab      
 no snmp trap link-status
 dot1x pae authenticator
 dot1x timeout quiet-period 2
 dot1x timeout tx-period 3
!
interface Vlan40
 ip address 172.16.40.1 255.255.255.0
 no ip proxy-arp
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
snmp-server community lauer RW
snmp-server community public RO
snmp-server community private RW
snmp-server trap-source Vlan40
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkdown linkup coldstart warmstart
snmp-server enable traps flowmon
snmp-server enable traps transceiver all
snmp-server enable traps call-home message-send-fail server-fail
snmp-server enable traps tty
snmp-server enable traps license
snmp-server enable traps auth-framework sec-violation
snmp-server enable traps cluster
snmp-server enable traps config-copy
snmp-server enable traps config
snmp-server enable traps config-ctid
snmp-server enable traps dot1x auth-fail-vlan guest-vlan no-auth-fail-vlan no-guest-vlan
snmp-server enable traps energywise
snmp-server enable traps fru-ctrl
snmp-server enable traps entity
snmp-server enable traps event-manager
snmp-server enable traps power-ethernet police
snmp-server enable traps cpu threshold
snmp-server enable traps ipsla
snmp-server enable traps vstack
snmp-server enable traps bridge newroot topologychange
snmp-server enable traps stpx inconsistency root-inconsistency loop-inconsistency
snmp-server enable traps syslog
snmp-server enable traps vtp
snmp-server enable traps vlancreate
snmp-server enable traps vlandelete
snmp-server enable traps flash insertion removal
snmp-server enable traps port-security
snmp-server enable traps port-security trap-rate 1
snmp-server enable traps envmon fan shutdown supply temperature status
snmp-server enable traps stackwise
snmp-server enable traps errdisable
snmp-server enable traps mac-notification change move threshold
snmp-server enable traps vlan-membership
snmp-server host 147.32.232.117 version 2c public  port-security
snmp-server host 172.16.40.2 v2c 
snmp-server host 172.16.40.2 version 2c write 
!
radius-server vsa send authentication
!
radius server pfnac
 address ipv4 147.32.232.117 auth-port 1812 acct-port 1813
 automate-tester username myuser idle-time 2
 key 7 071A32497D1D0B0A19150E1E372F28362D27
!
!
end
```

Also here are some other outputs :

**show aaa servers**

```
RADIUS: id 1, priority 1, host 147.32.232.117, auth-port 1812, acct-port 1813
     State: current UP, duration 633s, previous duration 0s
     Dead: total time 605813s, count 11
     Quarantined: No
     Authen: request 30438, timeouts 30438, failover 0, retransmission 22834
             Response: accept 0, reject 0, challenge 0
             Response: unexpected 0, server error 0, incorrect 0, time 0ms
             Transaction: success 0, failure 7604
             Throttled: transaction 0, timeout 0, failure 0
     Author: request 0, timeouts 0, failover 0, retransmission 0
             Response: accept 0, reject 0, challenge 0
             Response: unexpected 0, server error 0, incorrect 0, time 0ms
             Transaction: success 0, failure 0
             Throttled: transaction 0, timeout 0, failure 0
     Account: request 0, timeouts 0, failover 0, retransmission 0
             Request: start 0, interim 0, stop 0
             Response: start 0, interim 0, stop 0
             Response: unexpected 0, server error 0, incorrect 0, time 0ms
             Transaction: success 0, failure 0
             Throttled: transaction 0, timeout 0, failure 0
     Elapsed time since counters last cleared: 1w1h2m
     Estimated Outstanding Access Transactions: 0
     Estimated Outstanding Accounting Transactions: 0
     Estimated Throttled Access Transactions: 0
     Estimated Throttled Accounting Transactions: 0
     Maximum Throttled Transactions: access 0, accounting 0
     Requests per minute past 24 hours:
             high - 0 hours, 30 minutes ago: 20
             low  - 0 hours, 43 minutes ago: 0
             average: 2
```

**show aaa command handler**

```
AAA Command Handler Statistics:
    account-logon: 0, account-logoff: 0
    account-query: 0, pod: 0
    service-logon: 0, service-logoff: 0
    user-profile-push: 0, session-state-log: 0
    reauthenticate: 0, bounce-host-port: 0
    disable-host-port: 0, update-rbacl: 0
    update-sgt: 0, update-cts-policies: 0
    invalid commands: 0
    async message not sent: 0
```

**show radius statistics**

```
                                  Auth.      Acct.       Both
         Maximum inQ length:         NA         NA          1
       Maximum waitQ length:         NA         NA          5
       Maximum doneQ length:         NA         NA          2
       Total responses seen:          0          0          0
     Packets with responses:          0          0          0
  Packets without responses:       7604          0       7604
  Access Rejects           :          0
 Average response delay(ms):          0          0          0
 Maximum response delay(ms):          0          0          0
  Number of Radius timeouts:      30438          0      30438
       Duplicate ID detects:          0          0          0
 Buffer Allocation Failures:          0          0          0
Maximum Buffer Size (bytes):        260          0        260
Malformed Responses        :          0          0          0
Bad Authenticators         :          0          0          0
Unknown Responses          :          0          0          0
 Source Port Range: (2 ports only)
 1645 - 1646
 Last used Source Port/Identifier:
 1645/180
 1646/0

  Elapsed time since counters last cleared: 3w3d7h3m
Radius Latency Distribution:
<= 2ms :          0          0
3-5ms  :          0          0
5-10ms :          0          0
10-20ms:          0          0
20-50ms:          0          0
50-100m:          0          0
>100ms :          0          0

Current inQ length  : 0
Current doneQ length: 0
```

**show radius server-group all**

```
Server group radius
    Sharecount = 1  sg_unconfigured = FALSE
    Type = standard  Memlocks = 1
    Server(147.32.232.117:1812,1813) Transactions:
    Authen: 0   Author: 0   Acct: 0
    Server_auto_test_enabled: TRUE
     Keywrap enabled: FALSE
Server group packetfence
    Sharecount = 1  sg_unconfigured = FALSE
    Type = standard  Memlocks = 1
    Server(147.32.232.117:1812,1813) Transactions:
    Authen: 198 Author: 0   Acct: 0
    Server_auto_test_enabled: TRUE
     Keywrap enabled: FALSE
Server group  private_sg-7560
    Server(147.32.232.117:1812,1813) Successful Transactions:
    Authen: 0   Author: 0   Acct: 0
    Server_auto_test_enabled: TRUE
    Keywrap enabled: FALSE
```

**show aaa clients**

```
Dynamic Author Client 147.32.232.117 
    CoA: requests: 0, transactions: 0
        retransmissions: 0, active transactions: 0
        Ack responses: 0, Nak reponses: 0
        invalid requests: 0, errors: 0
    PoD: requests: 0, transactions: 0
        retransmissions: 0, active transactions: 0
        Ack responses: 0, Nak reponses: 0
        invalid requests: 0, errors: 0
    Average Ack response time: 0 msec
    Requests per minute past 24 hours:
        high - 0 hours, 50 minutes ago: 0
        low  - 0 hours, 50 minutes ago: 0
        average: 0

Dropped request packets: 0
```

**show aaa sessions** (last one)

```
Session Id: 2293
   Unique Id: 1864
   User Name: *not available*
   IP Address: 0.0.0.0
   Idle Time: 0
   CT Call Handle: 0
```

**show aaa user all** (last one)

```
--------------------------------------------------
Unique id 1865 is currently in use.
  No data for type 0
  No data for type EXEC
  No data for type CONN
  NET: Username=(n/a)
    Session Id=000008F6 Unique Id=00000749
    Start Sent=0 Stop Only=N
    stop_has_been_sent=N
    Method List=0
    Attribute list:
      07B361DC 0 00000001 session-id(408) 4 2294(8F6)
      07B36210 0 00000001 start_time(418) 4 Mar 31 2017 19:28:40
--------
  No data for type CMD
  No data for type SYSTEM
  No data for type VRRS
  No data for type RM CALL
  No data for type RM VPDN
  No data for type AUTH PROXY
  No data for type DOT1X
  No data for type CALL
  No data for type VPDN-TUNNEL
  No data for type VPDN-TUNNEL-LINK
  No data for type IPSEC-TUNNEL
  No data for type MCAST
  No data for type RESOURCE
  No data for type SSG
  No data for type IDENTITY
  No data for type ConnectedApps
Accounting:
  log=0x18001
  Events recorded :
    CALL START
    INTERIM START
    INTERIM STOP
  update method(s) :
    NONE
  update interval = 0
  Outstanding Stop Records : 0
  Dynamic attribute list:
    07B361DC 0 00000001 connect-progress(75) 4 Auth Timeout
    07B36210 0 00000001 pre-session-time(334) 4 86(56)
    07B36244 0 00000001 elapsed_time(414) 4 0(0)
    07B36278 0 00000001 bytes_in(146) 4 0(0)
    07B362AC 0 00000001 bytes_out(311) 4 0(0)
    07B39B3C 0 00000001 pre-bytes-in(330) 4 6484(1954)
    07B39B70 0 00000001 pre-bytes-out(331) 4 2012(7DC)
    07B39BA4 0 00000001 paks_in(147) 4 0(0)
    07B39BD8 0 00000001 paks_out(312) 4 0(0)
    07B39C0C 0 00000001 pre-paks-in(332) 4 25(19)
    07B33ECC 0 00000001 pre-paks-out(333) 4 18(12)
Debg: No data available
Radi: No data available
Interface:
  TTY Num = -1
  Stop Received = 0
  Byte/Packet Counts till Call Start:
    Start Bytes In = 4362869       Start Bytes Out = 8971432   
    Start Paks  In = 26485         Start Paks  Out = 25251     
  Byte/Packet Counts till Service Up:
    Pre Bytes In = 4369353       Pre Bytes Out = 8973444   
    Pre Paks  In = 26510         Pre Paks  Out = 25269     
  Cumulative Byte/Packet Counts :
    Bytes In = 4369353       Bytes Out = 8973444   
    Paks  In = 26510         Paks  Out = 25269     
  StartTime = 19:28:40 UTC Mar 31 2017
  Component = Dot1X
Authen: service=8021X type=EAP method=NONE Fallover-from= RADIUS
Kerb: No data available
Meth: No data available
Preauth: No Preauth data.
General:
  Unique Id = 00000749
  Session Id = 000008F6
  Attribute List:
    07B33ECC 0 00000001 port-type(225) 4 Ethernet
    07B33F00 0 00000081 interface(221) 20 GigabitEthernet1/0/1
PerU: No data available
Service Profile: No Service Profile data.
Unkn: No data available
```

Sorry for this much output, bud I will be able to connect to the switch in about two days, so I have tried to get as much info as possible.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What to you see on the RADIUS server?  It seems to not be responding to your switch.

Comment: @RonTrunk I am using PacketFence server as RADIUS server - I have not seen anything in logs (haven't done tcpdump on management interface, though), the ports 1812 and 1813 UDP are open, packetfence should be configured for the switch - but I am not sure with that configuration. However what I dont understand are the 1645 and 1646 ports in radius statistics

Comment: 1645 and 1646 are the source ports for the sockets in use - so the connection might be <source IP Address>:1645 -> 147.32.232.117:1812.  You can use this information when you're running a packet capture to find the traffic corresponding to the actual connection in use.  BTW - the output seems to suggest that the router is sending to the RADIUS server but isn't receiving anything back.  The packet capture can confirm this.

Comment: have you done a wireshark capture on the server to see if its getting the radius authentication requests from the switch?

Comment: @user3476261 no, I havent - I am kind of new in this area - will tcpdump suffice ? or is wireshark better ? or since the server does only have command-line access, is better to capture with wireshark/tcpdump and then analyze is somewhere with wireshark gui ?

Comment: tcpdump does the same job as wireshark but with a graphical interface. also do u have ping connectivity between server and switch?

Comment: I mean wireshark as a gui not tcpdump.

Comment: @user3476261 yes, I do have ping connectivity, both ways - I log into switch via ssh from server and I can ping server from switch. OK - and just to be clear, the RADIUS packets should come to UDP ports, dont they ? I will run tcpdump on the management interface and evaluate the output when I have the chance and let you know

Comment: yeah radius uses udp ...

Comment: @user3476261 I think I might have found something - the thing is, the server is VMWare virtual machine, one interface is connected to the internet (being used as the management interface) and the other is connected to the Cisco 3750 switch. When I sniff eth0 (management interface) - it won't show even a ping, but when I ping the server management interface IP from the switch and sniff on eth1 (the switch interface) it works. I feel this might be the problem, since the packets dont come to the management interface directly. Do you have any suggestions for further course of action ?

Comment: the switch as connectivity to which ip address of the server?

Comment: if u can ping 147.32.232.117 from your switch, probably u have a configuration error on your switch. I see from the show aaa servers that u have 7604 authentication failure attempts and 0 accepted. did u had this running before?

Comment: @user3476261 the switch has got 172.16.40.1 and the eth1 of the server has got 172.16.40.2 - but I can ping eth0 (147.32.232.117) from the switch. I had it set up for a while, but it showed the server dead, since I set up a wrong account to test the connectivity, after I set it up properly, it started seeing the sever alive - but the wrong configuration was there for a few days, so thats why there are that much of failures

Comment: I would change the radius server ip on the switch to 172.16.40.2 and see if u can authenticate successfully. since this is a vmware machine u can capture the traffic on the host machine by chosing the vmware interface u want to capture.

Comment: @user3476261 I might do that, but the reason of the 147.32.232.117 IP is that the radius server should be set to the management interface (eth0) IP address - I would guess it is because of the iptables from PacketFence. I will try that tomorrow when I get to the switch again, but wouldn't changing the iptables rules to allow 1812 and 1813 from eth1 be enough ? It still would get to the eth0, but the main problem here is imo that the iptables will just drop 1812 and 1813 port packets from non-management interface - what do you think ?

Comment: unfortunatly im not a linux expert and cannor help you with iptables, but I also would try to debug radius on the switch

Comment: @user3476261 I have tried turning on radius debug and aaa debug, but I have never done it before and I have expected that some more messages about aaa or radius would pop up, but nothing showed up

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin sorry, I was so excited to solve the problem that I have forgot to mark my solution as an answer - have done that now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it - the problem was that PacketFence iptables rules were set for RADIUS traffic from management interface, but I had to send it from another one. So adding some iptables rules made it work ! Thanks
(will accept answer when possible)

Comment: Also you can specify interface from which you will send packets to your RADIUS server: `ip radius source-interface <iface>`